# What is said in this film for the subtitles to use an expression about candles and annoyance? Is it an idiom?

Tags: traduction, expressions-idiomatiques, cinéma

**Question**

I am trying to convert some poor US English subtitles for a French movie into appropriate correct British English. There is a particular, I assume literal, translation that is obviously wrong:

> ”Your candle is bugging me”

The situation does not involve candles, flashlights or any kind of illumination but seems to indicate that the individual is mildly annoyed at being observed or crowed by others.

I have the movie and a reasonable level of French, but I can’t catch the sentence (only the « messieurs » that enclose it).

Any ideas what it might be?

**Context**

The movie is Jean Renoir’s 1962 “le caporal épinglé”. The only commercial subtitled version is in a collection of about six, which I bought second-hand during lockdown and now find this particular DVD to be cracked. I have just bought a copy of one without subtitles on eBay and have ripped it and am adding and editing subtitles downloaded from the internet. The scene in question is at about 80 min where Ballochet is leaving the hut to cut his way out of the camp.

Excellent film — much underrated.

**Clip available**

I have now mounted a 21 sec clip containing the audio at:
 https://www.davidleader.net/french/caporal.html .

Comment: Could the remark be made in reference to the situation referred to in French as "[tenir la chandelle](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/tenir_la_chandelle)" ("play gooseberry") ?

Comment: What is the French sentence?

Comment: @Toto C'est ce que le PO demande !!! ;-)  David... I've ben trying to find the script online but to no avail. Maybe someone's got the film here. Maybe by any chance this particular dialogue is in the book... (I haven't got the book, but audio available online). Sth you could do is record & upload this particular passage and link to it in chat ? Renoir is highly praised by film enthusiasts, not underrated in France. I haven't seen this film though.

Comment: Have you tried asking on [movies](https://movies.stackexchange.com). I don't know if they allow this kind of questions though. But they might know where to find movie scripts ...

Comment: This page http://davidbillemont3.free.fr/Sous-Titres%20Lf.html they say you can download the sous-titres français, .rar file. If you want to try.... And yes it's got Le caporal épinglé

Comment: @None: Je comprends que c'est un film français dont les sous-titres (anglais) sont incorrects. Si on pouvait avoir la phrase en français (éventuellement une bande audio), il serait plus facile de trouver une traduction correcte. Bien que dans ce cas, ce soit « Off Topic ».

Comment: @Toto Il ne comprend pas la phrase en français il nous la demande !

Comment: .srt file, I don't have the software to read it that so can't tell if it's worth it...

Comment: @Toto Oui offtopic mais si on peut l'aider en commentaires il pourra effacer ensuite.

Comment: @None .srt is plaintext; can be opened in any text editor

Comment: Created a copy of the subs here. Can't find anything at 80 min at first glance but open to anyone to look. Actually, I wonder if these are incomplete, perhaps just subtitles of foreign language parts within the film for the benefit of hearing French speakers, because otherwise there are stretches of 10 and 20 min with no dialogue. Need to find a full subs file for the deaf. https://pastebin.com/f9bj2yJ9

Comment: One possibility is that it's "bougez" (move), misinterpreted as "bougie" (candle).

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. Subtitles in French would be allow me to do the trick, but the download from the david billemont site (and the copy in pastebin from@LukeSawczak) is only a fraction of the whole.

Comment: The position of the phrase in the movie is 82 min and 19 sec, but the best thing would be for me to upload a clip to my own website. Will do that and post the URL in the question.

Comment: @Toto et al. I have now mounted a clip so you can hear the audio for yourself. Should have thought of that before.

Comment: I clearly hear: "messieurs, votre lumière me gêne" ("guys, your light is bothering me"), followed by the lights dimming. It seems he is requesting the lights to be dimmed before entering the room.

Comment: @Frank Many thanks. The quality of the film or perhaps the mental focus on the character prevented me from noticing that they had dimmed the lights. I understand the French and the translation is ok, but needs work to make the vocabulary of the character and the period. However that's my problem, not anyone elses. I guess the question needs to be removed now, as the premise is incorrect.

Comment: It's exactly what @Frank said. The reason it was translated by  "candle" is that the guy is holding a candle in order to give light. Translator's choice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can clearly hear: "**messieurs, votre lumière me gêne**" ("*guys, your light is bothering me*"), which is followed by the lights dimming. It seems the character by the door in the back is addressing the other characters massed in the front and requesting the lights to be dimmed before opening the door. There is no *candle* that I can tell of, he says "**lumière**" (*light*).

Comment: First many thanks. I can hear it now. (My personal problem is that I can often recognize what is being said in French only after I have read the subtitles.) Second, I now see that one of the men is actually holding a lighted match which he then extinguishes. For what it's worth I shall probably use a completely free translation of the situation and use something like "Gentlemen, the light please." as "bothering me", although correct, puts the emphasis on his annoyance rather than that he wants the match extinguished. But I'll sleep on it. Not being a professional I have the time.

Comment: messieurs is guys?

Comment: Monsieur, [singular] And it is bothering me. The light please sounds like turn it on or put it on. Not necessarily put it out.

Comment: @Lambie - I didn't go for the ultimate good translation, just tried to give some flavor. "Gentlemen" is probably much better.

Comment: But it is singular. As for the translation, it's fine. It's the OP's comment that is odd.

Comment: @Lambie I don't know - I think I'm hearing "Messieurs" plural. Not sure if it's singular. May be the case but it sounds like plural to me.